# DB Connection failed Sylius

Tags: php, symfony, sylius

I'm running MacOS Sierra and I'm trying to install locally Sylius. Although I (finally) managed to get it installed, I'm still facing connection error with the DB.

Here is the error I'm getting:

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T0nKw.png)

Do you have any idea of where might this come from?

Thanks!

Andrea

Comment: Can you connect to mysql from console with parameters from symfony?

Comment: Actually when I run this:

`/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql`

I receive another error

`Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)`

Comment: try to connect through port /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -P3306 -uroot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that the MySQL server is running. If using MAMP, check MAMP and ensure that MySQL is started. If not using MAMP, try this:

$ mysql.server start

See if you can connect through the console now. If so, you should be able to connect through Sylius.